# Spark Scala join Seq and lit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm learning Spark Scala programming, and have a prototype like this

```
val varible_a = varible_b.join(varible_c, Seq("column_a"))
    .withColumn ("column_b" , lit(50))
```

I don't know what's meaning of "`Seq`" and "`lit(50)`"

Looks like *varible_b* to join *varible_c*, but there is no join condition
Not sure what is meaning for "Seq"

Append a column "`column_b`" with "`lit(50)`", What is `lit(50)`?

Thank you very much,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

`Seq` is just a reference to a sequence of items, so this is a sequence of strings, with the only item being a string referencing `column_a`. In this case column_a is the column name for the two datasets to join on. There is an overload that takes a `String` though, so you don't need the `Seq` unless you need to join against more than one column.

Then `lit` is short for literal, so the new column will contain the value 50. It has to be wrapped in a `lit` because the parameter expects a `Column` and this wrapper converts the value into an integer literal `Column`

I hope that helps!